# Commands not working after editing .bashrc file

Tags: command-line, bash, bashrc

I need to install a programming software called cuda for my academic purpose. Googling how to install it on my Ubuntu 10.04, I found these and I have done that.

```
download the software
cd ~/Downloads 
sudo ./cudatoolkit_3.2.16_linux_32_ubuntu10.04.run

gedit ~/.bashrc
```

Add the following entries:

```
export CUDA_INSTALL_PATH=/usr/local/cuda 
export PATH=$CUDA_INSTALL_PATH/bin
```

Save and exit. 
Then run on bash.

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Now any command is not working saying: `The command could not be located because '/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.`

I can't understand as I am new to this. Can you please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add the following entries:

```
CUDA_INSTALL_PATH="/usr/local/cuda" 
PATH="$PATH:$CUDA_INSTALL_PATH/bin"
```

You don't need `export` in front of `PATH` variable in `.bashrc` file (`export` makes the variable available to sub-processes). When you use `PATH=$CUDA_INSTALL_PATH/bin` you reassign to the `PATH` variable only `$CUDA_INSTALL_PATH/bin` value and you lose the previous value (`...:/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:...`) which is absolutely necessary. You can check your `PATH` value in terminal with:

```
 echo $PATH
```